# How to identify Self Complementing Code?

Tags: digital-logic

Given that part of a self complementing code series looks like:

```
Base 6   | Code
---------+-------
0        | 000
1        | 
2        | 010
3        |
4        | 110
5        |
```

I am supposed to fill up what code will represent the Base 6 digits on the left. How should I go about doing that? For starters, how come 4 is 110?

Also, I am asked what codes are unused? isit 6 & 7?

** Sorry if I got my tags wrong*

Comment: Do you have any guesses as to what you should do? It is helpful to know what part you are struggling with.

Comment: @Kellenjb, I am wondering how might I start identifying which self complementing code is that, so that I can identify the rest of the codes eg. for 1, 3 & 5. I looked at my lecture notes and these doesn't look like any self complementing codes I see there like gray code etc. Notice 2 is 010 which is expected, but how did 4 become 110?

Comment: IMHO, belongs on stackoverflow or another site.

Comment: @Jason S, I thought StackOverflow is for programming? Like C#, Java, C++ etc? This seems like electronics, though I am learning this in my Computer Sci degree now

Comment: logic is in this gray area between programming and electronics. But maybe I was too fast on the close button -- if other people think it's on topic, then never mind.

Comment: why we have just four positive self-compelement codes?how we can prove it?why ifonly the sum of whights is 9 code is self=complement?

Comment: You should probably have to define what self-complementing code is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the table would go like this:

```
Base 6   | Code
---------+-------
0        | 000       (0+0+0)
1        | 001       (0+0+1)
2        | 010       (0+2+0)
3        | 101       (2+0+1)
4        | 110       (2+2+0)
5        | 111       (2+2+1)
```

The weighting for each of the bits is 2, 2, 1 (see sum in brackets above for how each value is calculated)
In "normal" binary code the weighting goes 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 etc. For example 4 is 100 (4 * 1) + (2 * 0) + (1 * 0)
As you can see reversing the bits turns n into 5-n.
e.g.
4 = 110 -> 5-4 = 001 (110, which is 4, when reversed to 001 which is 5-4 = 1)
3 = 101 -> 5-3 = 010 (101, which is 3, when reversed to 010 which is 5-3 = 2)

Here is a useful [document](http://www.inf.fu-berlin.de/lehre/WS00/19504-V/Chapter1.pdf) (see page 13)
Another one [here](http://nptel.iitm.ac.in/courses/Webcourse-contents/IISc-BANG/Digital%20Systems/Digital%20Systems.pdf)

EDIT (more info) - A self complementing code is one in which the bits can be reversed (1's complement) to produce the base-1's complement of the number. Usually this would be the 9's complement for decimal, but your example above is base 6 so you take the 5's complement (e.g. 6-1).
The weights of a self complementing code must add up to base-1 (e.g. 2+2+1=5) because 0 is always represented by all bits at 0 (e.g. 000 in your example), and n-1 needs to complement this (e.g. 5 = 111 in your example)
Knowing the above, it is simply a matter of trying different weightings to see what fits given the initial information. If we know 010 is 2, then the middle bits weight must be 2. Using this information we proceed to 110, and we now know the third bits weight must be 2 to make 4. This only leaves the first bit, which must have a value of 1 to adhere to the weights adding up to base-1 (e.g. 5) stated above (also you could discover this by taking the 1's complement of the code for 4 (110) to produce the code for (5-4=1) 001)

Comment: Where can I find more info on such things, I understand self complementing codes are for error checking/correction? But I dont get all that weighting, and `4 = 110 -> 5-4 = 001 (1)`

Comment: @jiewmeng - See updated answer (let me know if still not clear)

Comment: I think I understand this question, but in general, how do I define self complementing code? How do I identify the weighting of each bit? Isit just trial & error or something? There are 8421 (normal binary), 84-2-1, gray code, excess 3 (I believe there can be many variations) excess 12 maybe? Given a bunch of values, how can I identify if its self complementing & weighting? Sorry, electronics is not my strong point

Comment: @jiewmeng - I added some more info about workings and a second link.

Comment: In this case we also had exactly half the values given, so all we had to do was fill in their complement at the complementary positions. I.e. 1=~(5-1)=~110=001 and so on. Associating weights with the bits creates meaning for values that aren't in the set (i.e. 011 looks like a 3 too).

Comment: @YannVernier - yes, but we know 011 for 3 is not in the set since it's complement 5-3=2 is 010 (which we were given), rather than 100. I agree all we have to do is fill in the complements, but we can assign weighting to the bits also without violating any rules. It makes things clearer for the answer, to see how it was arrived at.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that in base 6, 5 is the complement of 0; in base \$N\$ complements add up to \$N-1\$. So I suppose the code for 5 will have the bits for code 0 complemented, and so on. There doesn't seem to be a specific reason why the code for 4 is 110, but you should be able to fill the gaps regardless.

*(I don't want to give you the complete solution because it looks like homework.)*